# Is there any tool for auto maintaining css code

Tags: css, code-maintainability

I have a huge CSS file which should be about 20'000 lines and it was accidentally saved on one line a while ago, making it extremely hard to read and maintain.

I was looking for a tool that would automatically separate lines of CSS files, but I am finding it difficult as I can't find an English definition describing what I'm after. Does anyone know any tool that would do that? I'm sure that such a tool exists somewhere.

It would help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Search for "unminify css", google returns plenty of tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as using SO's inbuilt feature, you could try looking at CSS Beautifiers.

Such as [http://codebeautify.org/](http://codebeautify.org/css-beautify-minify)

Most of these work with other languages too! Hope this helps

Comment: awesome! Beautify, would never have invented such definition by myself :)). Thank you, you helped me alot!

Answer (score 2):

Just use stackoverflow's code snippet tool (looks like `[<>]`) and click tidy...

Answer (score 0):

Use a splitter, replace system such as

```
FIND: "; "

REPLACE ";

"
```

because the `;` is the line end for CSS code so this would break all the code-lines into new lines, leaving only the brackets.

So then run the Find/Replace routine again to then add linebreaks outside the `}` characters.

```
FIND "}"

REPLACE: "}

";
```